# c++ function is publicly callable despite explicitly declared private

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-concepts

I am currently investigating why I am able to call a private function from a context where it should not be accessible from. I have already narrowed it down to a very simple example, but I am still unable to identify the issue.

[**LIVE example**](https://godbolt.org/g/XJDF8o)

This is my narrowed down version:

```
template<typename From, typename To>
concept bool ConvertibleNoNarrow = requires(From f, To t) {
    t = { f };
};

template<typename T>
class Wrapper {
    T t;
public:
    Wrapper(ConvertibleNoNarrow<T> u) : t(u) { }

private:
    // should be PRIVATE
    void operator()() { }
};

int main() {
    Wrapper<long> w(1);

    // should not be able to call this!
    w();
}
```

Comment: My first instinct is that its [a bug](https://godbolt.org/g/dTgtfd) with experimental stuff

Comment: Could you add whether that only happens for the call operator or for other functions, too?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt It does not seem to be related to `operator ()`, this is just a remnant of my full code.

Comment: What happens if you remove use of the concept?    e.g. make `Wrapper`s constructor accept a `T` rather than a `ConvertibleNoNarrow<T>`.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78715

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It should be private and you should not be able to call that operator in that way. I have tried it with removing the 'concept' and g++/clang do complain about that.

Comment: That's not an answer but a comment.

Comment: I cannot add comments. Too new :)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: There is no question to answer.